# Issue with building angular-cli through maven

Tags: java, node.js, angular, maven, angular-cli

I cloned an Angular/Java web application from the following github source https://github.com/prashantpro/report-viewer

I am having the following issue when running a mvn clean install:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) on project ng-reportapp: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

When I remove the following plugin from my ng-reportapp.pom.xml, the issue goes away:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>angular-cli build</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>ng</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                            <argument>--prod</argument>
                            <argument>--base-href</argument>
                            <argument>"/ng-reportapp/"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring? I figured that I am setting up the plugin incorrectly in my pom, however I can't resolve it. All help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you install angular cli with `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

Comment: Yeah - It says that "node_modules appears empty, you may need to run npm install"

Answer (score 0):

add an npm install execution to your pom

```
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>npm install</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                <executable>npm</executable>
                <arguments>
                  <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target/your/app</workingDirectory>
                <target>
                  <echo message="Npm install" />
                </target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
```

if that doesn't work try adding node modules directory to your ng build phase

```
<workingDirectory>${basedir}/target/your/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/</workingDirectory>
```

if that still doesn't work, try building with aot set to false

```
<argument>--aot=false</argument>
```